# Using variable in awk for get specific line in system activity reporter (sar)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sar

I'm trying to get specific parameter with awk every 15 minutes in my shell script. For example i want to get freemem:

```
$sar -r

SunOS CRP 5.10 Generic_138888-03 sun4v    06/01/2016
00:00:00 freemem freeswap
00:15:00   40317 14989925
00:30:00   43652 15043259
00:45:00   43650 15043147
......
```

Here my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
projectDashboard=/opt/player/test/logResc
date=`date +%Y%m%d`
host=`hostname`
cm=$(date +%M)
ch=$(date +%H)
if [ $cm -ge 0 ] && [ $cm -le 15 ];then
   sar -r | awk '$1 ~ /$ch:00:00/ {print ($2)}' | awk '{print '$date ' "|" '$host' "|" "memory" "|" $1}' >> $projectDashboard/"$host"_"$date"_00_15.log
elif [ $cm -ge 16 ] && [ $cm -le 30 ];then
   sar -r | awk '$1 ~ /$ch:15:00/ {print ($2)}' | awk '{print '$date ' "|" '$host' "|" "memory" "|" $1}' >> $projectDashboard/"$host"_"$date"_00_15.log
elif [ $cm -ge 31 ] && [ $cm -le 45 ];then
   sar -r | awk '$1 ~ /$ch:30:00/ {print ($2)}' | awk '{print '$date ' "|" '$host' "|" "memory" "|" $1}' >> $projectDashboard/"$host"_"$date"_00_15.log
elif [ $cm -ge 46 ] && [ $cm -le 59 ];then
   sar -r | awk '$1 ~ /$ch:45:00/ {print ($2)}' | awk '{print '$date ' "|" '$host' "|" "memory" "|" $1}' >> $projectDashboard/"$host"_"$date"_00_15.log
fi
```

Expected output:

```
20160307|00:15:00|CRP|memory|40317
20160307|00:30:00|CRP|memory|40317
20160307|00:45:00|CRP|memory|40317
20160307|01:00:00|CRP|memory|40317
20160307|01:15:00|CRP|memory|40317
.......
```

What I get:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

I already try to change the `$ch` to `${ch}` or `awk "$1 ~ /$ch:30:00/ {print ($2)}"` but still doesn't work. Is there any mistyped or wrong code in my script? I appreciate your help.

## UPDATE

I try to change the `$ch` with `awk -v` so the script is like this `awk -v ch="$(date +%H)" '$1 ~ /ch:00:00/'`. But I still get an error.

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

can someone tell me what is wrong in my script?

Comment: There should never be a need for `awk | awk`. 
Also, your quotes are all over the place.

Comment: General advice --- trim your script down, until the error disappears, then last change was what you needed.